# I am running Excel 2019 as a monthly subscriber. NONE of my F keys do what you guys say they are supposed to do! Suggestions?

Tags: excel

When I go into developer and then VBA, for example, the F8 key does nothing!  The CTRL+F8 calls up a screen for dual monitors which I do not have.  Is this newer version of Excel the problem or is it this laptop?

Comment: On some laptop, you sometime have a "Fn" key, generally on the left near the space bar, that must be pressed to access function keys.

Comment: In addition to the comment above, which is most likely the problem, some keyboards have a function lock button which acts like a caps/number lock for the function keys.